# Android 5.1: can not capture and get full-size image

Tags: java, android, android-camera, uri, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to capture and get a full size image using this [official android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

But it did not work, I found out that `mCurrentPhotoPath` returns `null` in `onActivityResult`

I define `mCurrentPhotoPath` in this code:

```
      private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
            );
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }
```

So please help me to save the image and get path of the image.

Comment: are you sure you have sd card in the device you are using?

Comment: debug and check `photoFile = createImageFile();` line. Do you getting `photoFile ` null?

Comment: No,  as the code says `if(photoFile !=null){startActivityForResult(...)}` and it starts, so it can't be `null`

Comment: That means `createImageFile();` method processed successfully. Means you are unable to see image in `mImageView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your process is being terminated while it is in the background. You need to make sure that you hold onto your path in the saved instance state `Bundle` for your activity or fragment that is calling `startActivityForResult()`.